# Helm chart ignoring config file or given key value

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki, promtail

I am not sure if the issue is related to promtail (helm chart used) or to helm itself.

I want to update the default host value for loki chart to a local host used on kubernetes, so I tried with this:

```
helm upgrade --install --namespace loki promtail grafana/promtail --set client.url=http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push
```

And with a custom values.yaml like this:

```
helm upgrade --install --namespace loki promtail grafana/promtail -f promtail.yaml
```

But it still uses wrong default url:

```
level=warn ts=2021-10-08T11:51:59.782636939Z caller=client.go:344 component=client host=loki-gateway msg="error sending batch, will retry" status=-1 error="Post \"http://loki-gateway/loki/api/v1/push\": dial tcp: lookup loki-gateway on 10.43.0.10:53: no such host"
```

If I inspect the config.yaml its using it doesnt use the internal url I gave during the installation:

```
root@promtail-69hwg:/# cat /etc/promtail/promtail.yaml 
server:
  log_level: info
  http_listen_port: 3101

client:
  url: http://loki-gateway/loki/api/v1/push
```

Any ideas? or anything I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Did provided in answer section post help you?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `client.url` is a value in the helm chart, but rather one inside a config file that your application is using.

Try setting [`config.lokiAddress`](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/promtail/values.yaml#L223-L239):

```
config:
  lokiAddress: http://loki-gateway/loki/api/v1/push
```

It [gets templated](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/promtail/values.yaml#L339-L353) into the config file I mentioned.

Comment: in the 5.* and 6.* version of `promtail` helm chart it's now `config: clients: -url`